# Is there an alterative to FileSystem.WriteAllText for editing a text file, I need to retain special characters

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am sending a text file to a printer via static IP. In my project I store the template text file and need a adjust the content before sending it.

Due to the character limitations of FileSystem.WriteAllText it strips all the special characters out of the file.
I am looking for an alternative method of editing/saving the file or a different way I could send the file without saving it.

Any ideas would be great, thanks.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim filePath As String = "C:\Users\..."
        Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath & "Template1.txt").Replace("MISCTEXT", "Hello World").Replace("QTY", "QTY 1")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filePath & "Template.txt", fileReader, False)

        Dim IP As String = "XXX.XX.XXX.XXX"

        Dim clientSocket As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
        clientSocket.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 9100))

        clientSocket.SendFile(filePath & "Template.txt")
        clientSocket.Close()

    End Sub
```

Here is a small example of the special characters.
Before:

ÃÿØÿÁþÄ ?Åÿ ÃÿÙÿÄ Åÿ ÃÿØÿÁþ€

After:

?�� ����� �� ������� �

Comment: There is an overload that accepts an Encoding. Admittedly, I don't use VB.NET but I would be very surprised if that didn't support "special" characters.

Comment: Actually, it works without specifying an encoding. What are you using to view the file?

Comment: @Crowcoder, I can view it in VS or in Notepad++

Comment: Are you talking about the file as received by the tcp client, or the file as written before sending? FileSystem.WriteAllText does not appear to be the problem as it works fine for me with your code. The file after sending over the socket could be another issue.

Comment: @Crowcoder, the file sends and prints fine if I do not edit it. You can see that I am saving and sending over the new file. If I send the original it is fine. And once the second file is created I can open them up and they are clearly different.

Comment: `Due to the character limitations of FileSystem.WriteAllText` - it has none. You are not providing the [encoding](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), so UTF-8 is [used by default](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writealltext?view=netcore-3.1#Microsoft_VisualBasic_FileIO_FileSystem_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_), which covers all characters. When I run your code, the file does not change.

Comment: If you use `My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText([Path], Encoding.UTF8)`, what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation and everyone's advice I have gotten this to work.

The problem was not only writing the file but reading it as well. By adding encoding as an overload the both read and write I am in business.
It did take me a number of tries to get the proper value for encoding, see revised code sample.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim filePath As String = "C:\Users\..."
        Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath & "Template1.txt", Encoding.Default).Replace("MISCTEXT", "Hello World").Replace("QTY", "QTY 1")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filePath & "Template.txt", fileReader, False, Encoding.Default)

        Dim IP As String = "XXX.XX.XXX.XXX"

        Dim clientSocket As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
        clientSocket.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 9100))

        clientSocket.SendFile(filePath & "Template.txt")
        clientSocket.Close()

    End Sub
```